# AWK not behaving in bash Script

Tags: bash, awk

When running the ssh line from a command line, it works.

From a bash script, it appears as: ($ variables inside of awk command are empty)

```
ssh user@server.example.com netstat --tcp| grep 'servervip3'| grep 'ldap'| awk ' == ESTABLISHED'| awk '{print }'| awk -F: '{print }' >>/somepath/somefile.txt
```

Script Section:

```
    for (( i=0; i<${arraylength}; ++i ))
    do
       # drop all beyond first period in SSH_ADDRESS[i] and add vip3
       host_grep="`echo ${SSH_ADDRESS[i]}|awk -F. '{ print $1 }'`vip3"
         ssh $FIRSTLOGNAME@${SSH_ADDRESS[i]} netstat --tcp| grep '$host_grep'| grep 'ldap'| awk '$6 == "ESTABLISHED"'| awk '{print $5}'| awk -F: '{print $1}' >>$seed_file

done
```

Any ideas?  Thanks    -jim

Comment: change `grep '$host_grep'` to `grep "$host_grep"`

Comment: Also, you should not need a pipeline with so many awk & grep. Single awk should be able to do it. But, that's optimization part.

Comment: And what about the chaining of `grep` and `awk`? That seems rather unnecessary.

Comment: Also, do not use the backtick \`command\` syntax. It's deprecated, and too easy to misread. Instead, use `$(command)`, which has the additional advantage that it can be nested

Comment: @jwilleke: Check out my so-called 'optimized' answer below

Comment: This is basically http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2):

Made some minor optimization over your original command as below with a strong dose of `awk`. I have combined 2 `grep` instances and an `awk` into one.

```
 ssh $FIRSTLOGNAME@${SSH_ADDRESS[i]} netstat --tcp | awk -v host="$host_grep" '(/host/ || /ldap/) && $6 == "ESTABLISHED" {print $5}' | awk -F: '{print $1}' >>$seed_file
```

I will explain how this works:-

1. Store the hostname to search as an `awk` variable `-v host="$host_grep"` so that it will be useful in the `regex` match.
2. `(/host/ || /ldap/) && $6 == "ESTABLISHED"` matches any line that has either host as stored in `$host_grep` or containing the keyword `ldap` AND having the column six value as `"ESTABLISHED"`
3. `awk -F: '{print $1}'` delimits your string using `:` and prints the value before it.